# What is the performance hit of using multiple WebGL context's

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm working on a WebGL application that works similarly to video compositing programs like After Effects.

The application takes textures and stacks them like layers. This can be as simple as drawing one texture on top of the other or using common blend modes like the screen to combine several layers.

Each layer can be individually scaled/rotated/translated via an API call, and altogether the application forms a basic compositing software.

**Now my question**, doing all this in a single WebGL canvas is a lot to keep track of.

*// Start webgl rant*

The application won't know how many layers there are ahead of time, and so textures coordinate planes and shaders will need to be made dynamically.

Blending the layers together would require writing out the math for each type of blend mode. Transforming vertex coordinates requires matrix math and just doing things in WebGL, in general, requires lots of code being a low-level API.

*// End webgl rant*

However, this could be easily solved by making a new canvas element for each layer. Each WebGL canvas will have a texture drawn onto it, and then I can scale/move/[blend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) the layers using simple CSS code.

At the surface, it seems like the performance hit won't be that bad, because even if I did combine everything into a single context each layer would still need its own texture and coordinate system. So the number of textures and coordinates stays the same, just spread across multiple contexts.

However deep inside I know somehow this is horribly wrong, and my computer's going to catch fire if I even try. I just can't figure out why.

With a goal of being able to support, ~4 layers at a time would using multiple canvases be a valid option? Besides worrying about browsers having a max number of active WebGL context's are there any other limitations to be aware of?

Comment: I think using multiple canvases would be the right approach. Otherwise you would have to re-render all the layers for each change. With multiple canvases you only render the layer in question, that should increase performance.

Comment: @BurhanB I'm not sure this is the case if all layers have the same size. Multiple <canvas> layers will involve compositing by the browser, and it might be in a similar runtime ballpark as blending multiple textures atop of one another within a single GL context. The amount of work is the same graphics wise, and there's not too much JS->GL call overhead, it just needs a handful to a dozen WebGL API calls. Unless benchmarks say otherwise, of course